# Error in Calling/Fetching wcf service

Tags: wcf

I have method like this

```
<OperationContract()>
<Web.WebGet(UriTemplate:="/GetBedTypeList?strErrMsg={strErrMsg}&chrErrFlg={chrErrFlg}&pcompanycode={pcompanycode}&pdiv={pdiv}&ploc={ploc}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)> _
Function GetBedTypeList(ByRef strErrMsg As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String), ByRef chrErrFlg As Char, _
                        ByVal pcompanycode As String,ByVal pdiv As Integer, _
                        ByVal ploc As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CWReadClasses.clsBedTypeMaster)
```

but it is giving error please help

Operation 'GetBedTypeList' in contract 'iBedTypeMaster' has a query variable named 'strErrMsg' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, WCF doesn't know by default how to convert a query string parameter (which is a string) into a `List(Of String)`, which is the type of your `strErrMsg` argument. You can either change it to a known type (strings, numbers, booleans), or you can, as the error suggests, to add a `QueryStringConverter` to your service to "teach" it how to convert from the query string into that type. You can find more information about query string converters in the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/09/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter.aspx.